# Laravel 5 return redirect is not working as it should

Tags: php, laravel-5, redirect

I'm having a controller with some functions. In every function I get user data by sharing it from the `Contoller.php`

In controller.php

```
public function share_user_data() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $this->checkValidation($user);
    $this->user = $user;
    View::share('user', $user);
}

public function checkValidation($user){
    if($user->email_activated == 0){
        var_dump($user->email_activated); // I get: int(0)
        return redirect('/verifyEmail');
    }
}
```

In the other controller

```
public function viewCategory(Category $category){
    $this->share_user_data(); // here's the check
    $this->get_site_lang();
    $products = $category->products;
    return view('category', compact('category','products'));
}
```

But I get the category view and not redirected to the `verifyEmail` route. How to fix this and why it's happening?

Comment: Your `var_dump` writes data to the output stream, which tells PHP to send the headers and start rendering the body. You cannot modify the headers after they have been sent, thus you cannot redirect.

Comment: it's better to return some kind of response from Contoller.php  and redirect on basis of that response in your controller , but still you can try public function checkValidation($user){
    if($user->email_activated == 0){
        return redirect('/verifyEmail')->send();
    }
}

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă The problem is not in var_dump I added it just to be sure that the value is 0. I removed it and still not redirecting

Comment: @SagarSainkar I just don't want to validate it separately in every function I could have a separate function to return verification result But planning to make it just one function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller function called by the route is the one responsible for the response. I guess it is `viewCategory()` in your example?

Your `viewCategory()` function is always returning `view()`. It must return `redirect()` instead. I think the main function should be responsible for picking the output of the request.

```php
private function checkValidation($user) {
    return $user->email_activated == 0;
}

public function viewCategory(Category $category) {
    $user = Auth::user();

    /* ... call to share_user_data() or whatever ... */    

    if ($this->checkValidation($user)) {
        return redirect('/verifyEmail');
    }

    return view('category', compact('category','products'));
}
```

Comment: was looking for another way without having to repeat the validation in all functions that require validation. I'll use the traditional method you provided. Thanks

Comment: You could have used the controller's constructor for that, but you can't get the user from there. You have to use a middleware, and it's the best practice anyway https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#protecting-routes